# Replacing Empty Cell by NULL in Ubuntu

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I would like to replace an empty cell between the || with NULL. I've tried doing so with the command sed and awk but I don't see any changes in the output text. Did I do something wrong in my process ?

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" } { for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i ~ /^ *$/) $i = NULL }; 1' 311-Public-Data-Extract-2011-clean.txt
```

This is the content of the txt file:

```
1100265887-101000386223||Unknown|Unknown|Unknown|Unknown|Unknown|Unknown|
```

This is what I wanted to get:

```
1100265887-101000386223|NULL|Unknown|Unknown|Unknown|Unknown|Unknown|Unknown|
```

Comment: Sorry, but "with no success" isn't a problem statement. Be specific!

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) for that output to your question (no comment).

Comment: Sorry @Quentin, I have removed the screenshot.

Comment: @ChristopheLe, not sure why you are setting field separators as `\t` because they aren't actually.

Comment: Can you have back to back empty cells? If so neither of the currently proposed solutions will work.

Comment: @EdMorton, Thank you Ed sir for letting know this. I have added an edit solution for same now kindly do lemme know if anything needs to be corrected sir, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following(written based on your shown samples).

```
awk '{gsub(/\|\|/,"|NULL|")} 1'  Input_file
```

EDIT: As per Ed sir's comment in case there are more than 1 empty fields are there so to handle that case.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i==""){$i="NULL"}}} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler `sed` command. `awk` is overkill for this simple task.

```
sed "s/||/|NULL|/g"
```